# Anaconda Navigator not allowing me to import environment

Tags: python, anaconda

When I click on import environment and then click on import from local drive but when I navigate to the directory of the desired the environment it just says "No items match your search".

[import environment dialogue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI91P.png)

[no items match your search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zzfv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the YAML file is in that directory? If you can't find it in the Anaconda Navigator file browser, try using Windows File Explorer. Once you have used another software to confirm that the YAML file is that directory, then we can troubleshoot Anaconda Navigator.

An alternative is to use Anaconda's cloud service, Nucleus, to backup (export) and import your environment across working environments.